# Are there any clear advantages to using JSON-LD Vs. JSON:API for REST endpoints?

Tags: rest, json-ld, json-api

I want to create a set of REST API endpoints to expose various data sources. I want my endpoints to comply with the [Richardson Maturity Model](https://restfulapi.net/richardson-maturity-model/), specifically with support for HATEOAS.

I've looked over both [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/) and [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) and they both seem to be a good fit in that they can both equally support REST and HATEOAS, however JSON:API has a bunch of other features which are more 'gRPC-like'.

Are there any clear advantages to using JSON-LD Vs. JSON:API for REST endpoints? What are the feature differences which are applicable to REST?